# How to use MUMPS with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mumps

I want to know how can i communicate with MUMPS using C# .NET? 
There is a requirement where i have to develop the UI in .NET using any of the .NET technology like ASP.NET, WPF or Silverlight etc. But the backend it will be old 60s MUMPS which is non relational database.

Is there any way to communicate to procedure of MUMPS using .NET? how can i use .NET with MUMPS together? I could not find much resource on Internet so thought to ask here

Request you to help and guide me with my above query.

Thanks

Regards
VJ

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357093/query-on-mumps-from-asp-net-c

Comment: Is the MUMPS solution already selected or in use?  If so, which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which MUMPS solution you will be using.

One possibility is the M/Gateway Services Integrator (MGWSI) developed by M/Gateway and provided free of charge.  From their web page ([M/Gateway Developments](http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/main/), then click on the *MGWSI Gateway* tab):

> The core MGWSI product is a generic integration engine, but we provide a range of specific integration gateways as part of the overall package, including:
>
> - Caché, GT.M or M21 to PHP (the m_php gateway) ;
> - Caché or GT.M to Java Server Pages (the m_jsp gateway) ;
> - Caché or GT.M to ASP.Net (the m_aspx gateway) ;

Another possibility is to use [KB_SQL](http://www.kbsystems.com/kbsql.html), which offer JDBC and ODBC drivers.  KB_SQL can be used with most of MUMPS solutions.

Another possibility may be to use [EsiObjects](http://www.esiobjects.org/), which supports both GT.M and InterSystem Caché.  From their FAQ :

> EsiObjects supports 4 fundamental gateways:
>
> - TCP/IP Gateway: This gateway is used to connect the EsiObjects Client Development VDE with any of the supported M systems. Additionally, The TCP/IP Gateway is also used to connect the runtime environment via an ActiveX Control.
> - COM Bridge: This is used with Microsoft clients built using VB, C++, C# , etc. It uses the TCP/IP Gateway and implements the ActiveX control for EsiObjects.
> - Java Gateway: This gateway uses the TCP/IP Gateway. There exists a set of methods in the ESI library that let you generate external Java Proxy classes from any EsiObjects class. All the connectivity is built in. Therefore, you can take the Java file that is created and use it within your Java environment, using the proxies automatically accesses the data on the EsiObjects Server.
> - CORBA ORB (aka EsiORB): This package is an add-on to EsiObjects. It is an implementation of the Object Management Groups (OMG) Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA). The ORB uses the TCP/IP Gateway.

If the MUMPS solution you use is InterSystem Caché, you could use [Caché Managed Provider](http://www.intersystems.com/cache/dotnet/index.html) solution.  That said, that solution would work only for InterSystem Caché, not for the other MUMPS solutions.

If the MUMPS solution you use is GT.M, you could use [PIP](http://www.fisglobal.com/products-technologyplatforms-pip) since it offers a JDBC driver.  That said, that solution would work only for GT.M, not for the other MUMPS solutions.

Comment: What about the InterSystem Cache technology  ?[link]http://www.intersystems.com/cache/dotnet/index.html Is it a wrapper for communicating with MUMPS from .NET.? I just want to know if i have to create an Application using .NET and MUMPS ? how can i achieve it ? What are different .NET framework available for the same? Is the Cache technology by InterSystem does the same job what i am looking for ? Yet its not clear to me

Comment: @VJGaur InterSystem Cache IS a MUMPS solution, like GT.M.  One difference between InterSystem Cache and GT.M is that, like your link point to, InterSystem offers a .NET integration solution for their Cache product.  I'm not familiar with InterSystem, so I don't know if that tools come with Cache or if you have to get it separately.  But like I said, the .NET integration solution available depends on which MUMPS solution you use, and how you want the two to interact together.